# Merits of JSON vs CSV file format while writing to HDFS for downstream applications

Tags: json, csv, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

We are in the process of extracting source data (xls) and injecting to HDFS. Is it better to write these files as CSV or JSON format? We are contemplating choosing one of them, but before making the call, we are wondering what are the merits & demerits of using either one of them.

Factors we are trying to figure out are:

- Performance (Data Volume is 2-5 GB)
- Loading vs Reading Data
- How much easier it is to extract Metadata (Structure) info from either of these files.

Injected data will be consumed by other applications which support both JSON & CSV.